# Change option label in WTForms-SQLAlchemy QuerySelectField

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, wtforms

I made a FLask application where my users can add some "Target" and edit them. Each Target has a Platform and each Platform has a category.

For example :

- the platform "Facebook" is in the Category "Social Network".
- the platform "Instagram" is in the Category "Social Network".
- the platform "Google" is in Category "Search Engine".

I have a form "New Target Field" where users need to select a Platform from a dropdown list. I managed to fill this list with a QuerySelectFied:

```
platform = QuerySelectField('Platform', validators=[DataRequired()], query_factory=GetPlatforms, get_label='name')
```

`GetPlatforms` is a function to load the list:

```
def GetPlatforms():
    return Platform.query.order_by('name')
```

This list displays several times the same platform name. They are different platforms as these platforms have different categories. So everything is fine.

The problem is users can't distinguish the platforms as there is only 1 label in the dropdown list. See the screenshot below for a better understanding of the issue:

[image]

How can I change the label for each option so the category is next to the name?

Answer (score 1):

add a model object’s `__str__` or `__unicode__` to your model and set no `get_label='name'`

for example:
in your db-model:

```
class Platform(db.Model):
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), primary_key=True)
    platform = db.Column(db.String(64))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.name, self.platform)
```

and in your form:

```
platform = QuerySelectField('Platform', validators=[DataRequired()], query_factory=GetPlatforms)
```

Also see the doc:

> get_label – If a string, use this attribute on the model class as the
> label associated with each option. If a one-argument callable, this
> callable will be passed model instance and expected to return the
> label text. Otherwise, the model object’s **str** or **unicode** will
> be used.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this:

```
Platform.query.distinct(Platform.name).order_by('name')
```